# Header [Authorization] is not working in Reactj for ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-core-webapi

Please tell me what could be the issue: I've configured React and ASP.NET Core Web API to use JWT tokens, but for some reason, when React requests resources with the `[Authorize]` attribute, it gets denied, even though the header seems to be configured correctly.

Here are snippets of the code, and if you need anything else:

[image: http request]

[image: http answer]

Code:

```
import useRefreshToken from "./useRefreshToken";
import useAuth from "./useAuth";
import {useEffect} from "react";
import {axiosPrivate} from "../api/axios";


const useAxiosPrivate = () => {
    const refresh = useRefreshToken();
    const {auth} = useAuth();

    useEffect(() => {
        const requestIntercept = axiosPrivate.interceptors.request.use(
            config => {
                if(!config.headers['Authorization']){
                    config.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${auth?.jwtToken}`;
                }
                return config
            }, (error) => Promise.reject(error)

        );

        const responseIntercept = axiosPrivate.interceptors.response.use(
            response => response,
            async (error) => {
                const prevRequest = error?.config;
                if ((error?.response?.status === 403 || error?.response?.status === 401) && !prevRequest?.sent){
                    prevRequest.sent = true;
                    const newAccessToken = await refresh();
                    console.log("New Token After Response in useAxiosPrivate: " + newAccessToken );
                    prevRequest.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${newAccessToken}`;
                    return axiosPrivate;
                }
                return Promise.reject(error)
            }
        )

        return () => {
            axiosPrivate.interceptors.request.eject(requestIntercept);
            axiosPrivate.interceptors.response.eject(responseIntercept);
        }
    },[auth,refresh])

    return axiosPrivate;
}

export default useAxiosPrivate; 


export const axiosPrivate = axios.create({
    baseURL:apiUrl,
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials":"true",
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
    }
});
```

C# code:

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [Authorize]
    public class CartsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ICartRepository _cartRepository;

        public CartsController(ICartRepository cartRepository)
        {
            _cartRepository = cartRepository;
        }

        [HttpPost("AddDish")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddDish(AddDishToCartRequestModel model)
        {
            try
            {
                var responseModel = await _cartRepository.AddDishToCartAsync(model);
                return Ok(responseModel);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return BadRequest(e.Message);
            }
        }

-------------
 
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using WebApiForReact.Data;
using WebApiForReact.Models.Identity;
using WebApiForReact.Models.Order;
using WebApiForReact.Repositories;
using WebApiForReact.Repositories.AuthService;
using WebApiForReact.Repositories.CartRepository;
using WebApiForReact.Repositories.CategoryRepository;
using WebApiForReact.Repositories.OrderRepository;
using WebApiForReact.Services;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
var configuration = builder.Configuration;

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
});

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidAudience = "RestaurantAPI",
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["JWTSettings:ValidIssuer"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("SecretRestaurantTestApiKey"))
    };
});

builder.Services
    .AddIdentity<UserApp, IdentityRole>(options =>
    {
        options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
        options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
       
    })
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

builder.Services
    .AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("PolicyApp",
            build => build
                .SetIsOriginAllowed(_ => true)
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials()
            );
        
    });


builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Program));

builder.Services.AddScoped<IImageRepository, ImageRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IDishRepository, DishRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICategoryRepository, CategoryRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IOrderRepository, OrderRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICartRepository, CartRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IJwtService, JwtService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IAuthService, AuthService>();

var app = builder.Build();

using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    await SeedData.SeedIdentity(scope.ServiceProvider);
}

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseCors("PolicyApp");

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Comment: Would you kindly try by setting the `ValidateAudience = false,` to true.In addtion, please double check your application location URL is correct. 
Because the most common reason for 302 either the resource has been "Moved Temporarily" which means, the requested resource has been temporarily moved to a different location 
or may be a user tries to access a protected resource without being authenticated, the server may respond with a 302 status code and redirect the user to a login page or an authentication endpoint. So please double the above configuration accordingly.